# Will ASP.NET MVC 2 be supported in Visual Studio 2008 / .NET 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

The ASP.NET MVC 2 preview 2 was first released for Visual Studio 2008 only. Later on, it was also included in Visual Studio 2010 beta 2. I've read that ASP.NET MVC 2 will be included in Visual Studio 2010 RTM, but is there any official word on weather or not ASP.NET MVC 2 will be officially supported in Visual Studio 2008 / .NET 3.5?

Comment: if not, i will boycott these morons ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fourth paragraph down in the blog post below indicates that it will be available for VS 2008 SP1: [ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 1 Released](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/30/asp.net-mvc-released.aspx)

> As mentioned in the roadmap and
>   elsewhere, ASP.NET MVC 2 will run on
>   both ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 and ASP.NET 4. We
>   will be shipping ASP.NET MVC 2 in the
>   box with Visual Studio 2010 and be
>   making a separate installer for Visual
>   Studio 2008 SP 1 available via
>   download.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the edit Moayad I should have included the quote from the start.